# Rails Model association type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have the following tables: users, friends, interests, and holidays. The purpose of this app is to recored users interests and the holidays they celebrate (including friends birthdays, anniversaries ect) as well as what the interests of the friends so i can send them reminders with relevant content. Anyways:

A user will have interests
A user will have friends
Friends will also have Interests
A user will have holidays they celebrate (a list of about 10)
-If mothers day, fathers day, or valentines day is selected (in the holidays) I will need to store the persons name and their interests as well

So im wondering how to set these up.. The tricky ones are the interests and holidays.

Should interests be polymorphic so users and friends can both access? Or has many :through?

What about holidays? How would those work to record the name and also persons interests?

Thanks! im really struggling for this one, probably overcomplicating things..

Comment: If me and a friend of mine signs up, is my friend both a Friend and a User? (i.e. two different models) If they are separate models, interests should definitely have a polymorphic relationship to users and friends, and holidays might have one, but you have only specified that holidays are related to users, and not necessarily friends.

Comment: Thanks! No, there is no social networking aspect to the site, users are individual and have no relationship with other users of the site. The purpose of 'friends' is for the user to enter the date of that persons birthday, their interests, and then I will send them a reminder with offers related to that friends interests. Similar with holidays. If a user selects 'anniversary', i will ask them the name, date and interests of that person so i can send them related offers. Make sense?  Thanks a ton!

Comment: ok, next question - are interests intended to be shared between users, like a single interest record can be connected to many users/friends, or are interests just strings?

Comment: well there is a set list of 30 interests that i will seed the database with.. They will have to select from that list, cannot add any others.. But they are just strings, so each record will belong to a unique user i guess?.. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't have to. `have_and_belongs_to_many` is there for that. going to leave an answer for how i would model this.

Comment: the key is that I need to record the users interests as well. So users have interests and users friends have interests. Wanted to clarify that.. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I think I understand what you want to do, this is how I would model this:

`User`:

```
has_many :friends
has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests
has_many :user_holidays
has_many :holidays, :through => :user_holidays
```

`Friend`:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests
```

`PersonInterest`:

```
belongs_to :interest
belongs_to :person, :polymorphic => true
```

`Interest`:

```
has_many :person_interests
has_many :people, :through => :person_interests # may need an `inverse_of` here
```

`UserHoliday`:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :holiday
```

`Holiday`:

```
has_many :user_holidays
has_many :users, :through => :user_holidays
```

With these set up, you should be able to do the queries you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, per my previous question, the "has_many interests, through => :person_interests" will allow me to differentiate between the users own interests, and the users friend's interests correct? Thank again!

Comment: Yeah, you can do, for example, `@user.interests` and `@user.friends.first.interests` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: shouldnt there be a Person model? "belongs_to :person"

Comment: No, not for a polymorphic relationship. It's just a representative name for what can be connected to it, which in this case can be either a `User` or a `Friend`.

Comment: Got it.. now i understand the whole thing.. perfect. Thanks again

Comment: As far as database fields, the `PersonInterest` model will need both `person_id` and `person_type` fields.

Comment: Great.. was hoping i had that right..One last question.. So when the user selects a holiday (say 'anniversary') and i ask them for the name, date and interests of the spouse.. How could the interests through holiday connection work?

Comment: Little confused about the fields needed for Interest, UserHoliday, & Holiday.. For brevity i thought i would just ask what you were thinking for these instead of explaining my confusion..

Comment: How did you want interests to be related to holidays? You can just store the (spouse/mother/father), and then get their interests when needed, or store them all (person + interests) at the same time.

Comment: As modeled above, `Interest` would at least need a name, `UserHoliday` would have `user_id` and `holiday_id` fields, and `Holiday` would need at least a name, like the `Interest` class.

Comment: ok cool.. ya i was referring more to special fields to complete the associations rather than standard attributes (:name, :date, ect)..thanks a million, have been struggling with this one but think you got it straight for me!

Comment: Pretty much everything is working great! Running into one error in setting up the form for the friends interests.. Its here if you have any clues, thanks!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661600/nested-form-error-in-rails-app

Comment: I saw it, but I have no experience with simple_form, unfortunately, and your issue is specific to that.

Comment: simple form allows me to include standard erb, so i could replace that section of the form (form_for) with just normal syntax i believe.. How could i rewrite just that line thats giving me trouble?

Comment: My initial guess would be to go through the interests list, and render a checkbox that's populated with whether the friend in question has that interest. You want to print out checkboxes for all interests, even if the friend doesn't have that interest, right?

Comment: So basically the first step of registration the user enters their own information and interests (working fine). The second step is asking them for their friends names & birthdays, and also interests of those friends. So i just need all of the interests checkboxes to show up but save related to the friend not the user. Thanks

Comment: Ok. In that case you're probably better off listing the interests, and linking them to the friend in the controller, rather than trying to do a `fields_for` with nested attributes, because there will be some interests that need to be listed even if the friend doesn't have them.

Comment: Ok so im thinking ill just create a new form entirely to collect the information about the friend... so if i do a new: form_for @friend do |f| , would <%= f.association :interests ... %> then save related to the friend and not the user? (Interests are pre populated so that would display all)

Comment: Seems ok. This is a pretty complex scenario though so it's hard to know if it's completely correct.