# Nested form error in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, simple-form

Models relevant to this question: user, friend, interest, person_interest. Person_interest is polymoprhic and can store interests that either belong to a user or a friend.

Interests is pre-populated with approx. 30 interests. When a user registers they are asked to select their own interests, then lower in the form enter in their friends names select the interests of that person.

Trying to achieve this with `<%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>`

but getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in User_steps#show

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/views/user_steps/show.html.erb where line #30 raised:

undefined method `to_i' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
Extracted source (around line #30):

27:         :end_year => Date.today.year - 12,
28:         :order => [:month, :day, :year ] %>
29:       <%= friend_f.input :gender, :collection => ['male','female'] %>
30:       <%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>
31:     <%end%>
32:   
33: 
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/user_steps/show.html.erb:30:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_user_steps_show_html_erb__1202886937753978667_70281885932700'
app/views/user_steps/show.html.erb:23:in `block in _app_views_user_steps_show_html_erb__1202886937753978667_70281885932700'
app/views/user_steps/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_user_steps_show_html_erb__1202886937753978667_70281885932700'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"show"}
```

And here's the form..

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :address, :live => true  %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode %>
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date, :start_year => 1900,
    :end_year => Date.today.year - 12,
    :order => [ :day, :month, :year] %>
  <%= f.input :gender, :collection => [:male, :female] %>


    <h4>Select your top 3 interests..</h4>
      <%= f.association :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>

    <h4>What holidays do you celebrate?</h4>
      <%= f.association :holidays, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %> 



<h4>Add up to 10 friends birthdays that you would like to remember..</h4>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :friends do |friend_f| %>

      <%= friend_f.input :name %>
      <%= friend_f.input :dob, :label => :Birthday, :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year - 90,
        :end_year => Date.today.year - 12,
        :order => [:month, :day, :year ] %>
      <%= friend_f.input :gender, :collection => ['male','female'] %>
      <%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>
     <%end%>


 <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
      <%end%>
```

Git repo is here: https://github.com/nelsonkeating/ReminDeal

Comment: So its this line " <%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have any reasons to avoid `friend_f.association` ?

```
<%= friend_f.association :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>
```

Works for me.
Or change `:interests` to `:interest_ids` in kasper's code, also should work.

```
<%= friend_f.input :interest_ids, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false, :collection => Interest.all %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write code `<%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>` with `:collection` key.
For example:

```
<%= friend_f.input :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false, :collection => Interest.all %>
```

Comment: that gives me the following error: "NameError in User_steps#show .....uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Interests"

Comment: In kasper's code, change `:collection => Interests.all` to `:collection => Interest.all` and try that. The model should be singular.

Comment: I do it all the time. Hope that helps! If that doesn't solve the problem, I may have another solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!.. now im getting "undefined method `to_i' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation"

Comment: @StephRose what was your alt. idea?? Thanks again.